# QuickCheck sequential Map key generation

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I am trying to test a logic of custom data type. It receives a Map Int String as a parameter and then I need to add an element into the Map inside the object.

Type declaration and insertion function look like this:

```
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as M
import Data.UUID (UUID)
import Control.Monad.State
import System.Random

type StrMap = M.IntMap String
type MType = State StdGen

data MyType = MyType {
    uuid :: UUID,
    strs :: StrMap
} deriving (Show)

create :: StrMap -> MType MyType
create pm = do
    state <- get
    let (uuid, newState) = random state
    put newState
    return $ MyType uuid pm

strsSize :: MyType -> Int
strsSize e = M.size $ strs e

addStr :: MyType -> String -> MyType
addStr e p = e { strs = M.insert (strsSize e) p $ strs e }
```

It is important to have sequential keys in the Map, so having [0, 1, 3] is not acceptable.
I was trying to test it using HSpec with QuickCheck:

```
main :: IO ()
main = hspec spec

spec :: Spec
spec = describe "Creation and update" $ do
    QuickCheck.prop "Check map addition" $ do
        \xs str -> monadicIO $ do
            state <- run(getStdGen)
            let (result, newState) = runState (create xs) state
            run(setStdGen newState)
            let result' = addStr result str
            assert $ (strsSize result) + 1 == strsSize result' -- fails here
```

The problem is that QuickCheck generates random keys and I am not sure how do I force it to generate a sequential keys for the Map. The problem with absense of the sequense is that function addStr may override values in case of repetetive keys, which is not desirable behavior.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all the help! After a long discussion and some kind of a thinking  I ended up with the following solution:

```
spec :: Spec
spec = describe "Creation and update" $ do
    QuickCheck.prop "Check map addition" $ do
        \xs str -> not (null xs) Property.==> monadicIO $ do
            state <- run(getStdGen)
            let mp = M.fromList $ zip [0..(length xs)] xs
            let (result, newState) = runState (create mp) state
            run(setStdGen newState)
            let result' = addStr result str
            assert $ (strsSize result) + 1 == strsSize result'
```

Basically, I had to generate some random set of strings and them convert in into a map manually. It is probably not the most elegant solution, but it works as needed.

Comment: When you say that QuickCheck is generating "random keys", do you mean that it is generating random `StrMap`s? This question is very hard for me to understand.

Comment: This is not a _minimum reproducible example_ so I cannot be sure, but `(M.size . strs result)` looks like a type error. It is very difficult to answer a question like this if your example code doesn't compile.

Comment: It is generating a map with the content like following: {(0, "xyz"), (3, "qwerty")} or just {(5, "asd")}. In my case I need to make sure that keys always start from zero and there is no gaps between them, i.e. keys should always be 0,1,2,3,4,...

Comment: I don't think that is what you need at all. I don't see how that is relevant to the property you are checking. You never actually test the _values of the keys_ in any way, only the relative sizes of successive maps.

Comment: When I have a map with values {(0,"abc"),(2,"qwerty")} and I insert another value using addStr function it checks the size of the map, which is 2 in this example, and adds new element with the key equals to the size and a new value. In this example, I already have this key (2) in the map, so the value will be just overriden, which is not what I need.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. You shouldn't rely on QuickCheck to build structures that maintain some external invariant that your code requires unless you somehow tell QuickCheck to do that. One way you could do this would be to generate a small integer `n` and an infinite list of strings and to successively add `n` strings to an empty map. Then at any point, adding one more should have the behavior you expect.

Comment: I still suspect that there are a number of issues that prevent your code from compiling, which makes it difficult to give more concrete advice. Another one is that `create` has the wrong type to be used as you do to construct `result'`.

Comment: Could you please clarify what part doesn't compile? I assume you mean the test itself as the code being tested compiles well?

Comment: Surely you can clarify whether it does or doesn't compile. It is your code and you can try to compile it. I was wrong about the `addStr` being a type error, but I have to guess about these things because your code as provided is incomplete and can't be compiled at all.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was focusing on the code itself instead of the test. Changed it, so it compiles now (only some imports are missing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `QuickCheck` to generate arbitrary data that satisfies some complex invariant, which can be difficult, you can use QuickCheck to generate fully arbitrary data from which you can then construct data that satisfies the invariant (by some method external to the system being tested which you trust to be correct).

The invariant in this case is given as "keys must be contiguous", but is actually "keys must be contiguous *and start from 0*". This is sufficient, but more than necessary. The minimal invariant required by `addStr` is "the map must not contain a key that is the size of the map", since that is the key we intend to insert. By simplifying the constraint, we also make it easier to satisfy: we can generate an arbitrary map (which may contain the bad key) and then delete the bad key, giving a satisfactory map.

I'll also note that the UUID (and thus the mechanism for generating it, which requires `State` and perhaps `IO`) is irrelevant to the property being tested. This means we can construct the `MyType` with any `UUID` we have lying around (like the `nil` UUID provided by the package) and avoid the monadic stuff:

```
spec :: Spec
spec = describe "Creation and update" $ do
  QuickCheck.prop "Check map addition" $ do
    \strmap -> -- we don't actually care what the String being inserted is for this test
      let myType = MyType UUID.nil (M.delete (M.size strmap) strmap) -- Enforce the invariant
      in assert $ strsSize (addStr myType "") = strsSize myType + 1
```

If you wanted to, you could also make an instance of `Arbitrary` for `MyType` that does something like this, or something that satisfies the stronger invariant (which may be required for other tests). I'll leave that as an exercise for you, but feel free to ask more questions if you get stuck trying it.